C#+MongoDB BulkInsert documents with DbRef
I'm writing in C# .Net and MongoDb
In C# I have an object X
public class X {
public string Name {get;set;}
public string InnerBuffer {get;set}
}

InnerBuffer is a Json string.
In my mongo db I have 2 collections: XObjects and InnerObjects.
The XObject schema in mongo is
public class XObject{
public string Namw {get;set;}
public MongoDBRef InnerBufferRef {get;set;}
}

I want to insert the InnerBuffer json as a document into the InnerObjects collection,
then create a new XObject that will contain the Name of the X object and a dbRef to the InnerBuffer document that was previously inserted to the database, and then insert that XOjbect to the XObjects collection.
for a single insert I simply do
X _x = new X() {Name="xxx", InnerBuffer="<a json string>"};

// insert the InnerBuffer
var collection = _db.getCollection<BsonDocument>("InnerObjects");
BsonDocument innerBufferDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(_x.InnerBuffer);
collection.InsertOne(innerBufferDoc);

// update the xObject
XObject _xObject = new XObject(){Name=_x.Name, InnerBufferRef=new MongoDbRef("InnerObjects", innerBufferDoc["_id"].asObjectId)};

// insert the xObject
var xObjectsCollection = _db.getCollection<XObject>("XObjects");
xObjectsCollection.InsertOne(_xObject);

That works fine.
Now, how can I accomplish that in a bulkInsert or InsertMany?
What would be the most efficient way to do that?
Thanks.

you should use InsertMany and pass _xObject as array

@dododo But  I'll still have to insert all the inner objects, and then iterate over them and update the xObjects. Isn't there any way to do that in one query?

MongoDBRef doesn't make any magic to you, if you need to insert inner object, than you have to add them into your model
